# loops application in dataframe to find output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
dict={'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[10,20,233,29,2],'C':[10,20,3040,230,238]...................}
```

and

```
df= pd.Dataframe(dict)
```

In this manner I have 20 columns with 5 numerical entry in each column
I want to have a new column where the value should come as the following logic:

```
0      A[0]*B[0]+A[0]*C[0] + A[0]*D[0].......
1      A[1]*B[1]+A[1]*C[1] + A[1]*D[1].......
2      A[2]*B[2]+A[2]*B[2] + A[2]*D[2].......
```

I tried in the following manner but manually I can not put 20 columns, **so I wanted to know the way to apply a loop to get the desired output**
:

```
lst=[]
for i in range(0,5):
    j=df.A[i]*df.B[i]+ df.A[i]*df.C[i]+.......
    lst.append(j)
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential solution is the following. I am only taking the example you posted but is works fine for more. Your data is df

```
   A    B     C
0  1   10    10
1  2   20    20
2  3  233  3040
3  4   29   230
4  5    2   238
```

You can create a new column, `D` by first subsetting your dataframe

```
add = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'A']
```

and then take the sum over all multiplications of the columns in `D` with column `A` in the following way:

```
df['D'] = df['A']*add.sum(axis=1)
```

which returns

```
   A    B     C     D
0  1   10    10    20
1  2   20    20    80
2  3  233  3040  9819
3  4   29   230  1036
4  5    2   238  1200
```